# Michael Hatl's Rails Tutorial Chapter 2: Errno::ENOENT in UsersController#index when testing /users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

When generating toy_app using scaffolding I can go to the root site using the local server, but when I try to go to the page /users I get the following error message: "Errno::ENOENT in UsersController#index"

The page should allow me to enter a new user.

When I try to restart the server and run `rails server -b $IP -p $PORT`I get the following:

```
sunny_dee@rails-tutorial:~/workspace/toy_app (master) $ rails server -b $IP -p $PORT
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.0 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:8080
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2015-04-27 18:06:55] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-04-27 18:06:55] INFO  ruby 2.1.5 (2014-11-13) [x86_64-linux]
Exiting
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/socket.rb:206:in `bind': Address already in use - bind(2) for 0.0.0.0:8080 (Errno::EADDRINUSE)
```

Comment: You'll need to paste the actual code here, as well as the actual error message and any other relevant information. Linking to your live version is problematic because it'll change as you fix or break things.

Comment: I'm very new to Rails so I'm sorry if I sound like an idiot. I search for explanation about the error message and the recommendation was to restart the server. So on the terminal I used Ctrl+C and then typed 'rails server -b $IP -p $PORT' but I still get that the address was already in use

Comment: Are you sure the other rails server instance is closed down in the c9 workspace? If so and it still won't work, try searching for the rails process (do `ps aux | grep rails`) and see if you can find it and manually shut it down (`kill -9 [the process ID`).

Answer (score 2):

I finally got it to work by restarting the workspace. I'm guessing that is what restarted the local server. I was trying Ctrl-C but it was not working.

The tutorial uses Cloud9 and since it's a cloud IDE closing/logging out did nothing but when I clicked on the button to the left of "Share" on the top right corner and the clicked on "Restart" the page ran correctly.

Hopefully my stupid question can help someone else as well. Thanks everyone that took the time to contribute :)

Answer (score 0):

If you running this application in your local Linux system just use -

```
rails server
```

Then you can access your site using http://localhost:3000/

You can also specify which port to run on using this command -

```
rails s -p 3001 -P tmp/pids/server2.pid
```

Then you can access using 3001 port.

You are getting that error because your 8080 port is already in use by some other process.